# Cropping Image With ImageProcessor not working on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageprocessor

I use [this plugin](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/)  for cropping image in my asp.net mvc 5 application. When I launch application in localhost every thing are right and I can crop image successfully. But I cant crop images on server. I don't get any error and image saved in original size. I also uploaded config folder at the root of website and my web config has default setting according to [ImageProcessor.Web configuration](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/configuration/).

I don't know what the problem is and what should I check.

Can anyone help me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that CloudFlare prevent Imageprocessor work as well as localhost.
When I disable cloudflare every thing was OK.